# How to merge multiple grouped output files in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I have a process that outputs multiple files as tuple. Like this:

```
[chr1,[[chr1.chunk1.bgen],[chr1.chunk1.stat],[chr1.chunk2.bgen],[chr1.chunk2.stat],[chr1.chunk3.bgen],[chr1.chunk3.stat]]]
```

How could I get `chr1.merged.bgen` and `chr1.merged.stat` . I want to use `cat` to merge all these chunks.

I tried:

```
input:
tuple val (chrom), file('*.bgen'),file('*.stat') from my_output
"""
cat "${chrom}.${*.bgen}" > "${chrom}.merged.bgen"
cat "${chrom}.${*.stat}" > "${chrom}.merged.stat"
"""
```

But got " `Input tuple does not match input set cardinality decalred`
Also for:

```
input:
tuple val (chrom), path(bgen),path(stat) from my_output
"""
cat "${bgen}" > "${chrom}.merged.bgen"
cat "${stat}" > "${chrom}.merged.stat"
"""
```

Same error.
I also tried to use `my_output.collect()` and `my_output.toList()` But getting same error.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In your example process, you defined 3 input variables, but you only provide 2. That's what the error message is trying to tell you - in fact I think this is only a warning.

The way your process' input is defined, nextflow would expect it to be in this form:

```
[chr1,[chr1.chunk1.bgen, chr1.chunk2.bgen, chr1.chunk3.bgen],[chr1.chunk1.stat, chr1.chunk2.stat, chr1.chunk3.stat]]
```

So one option would be to reformat your channel before you feed it into that process. Like this for example:

```
my_output
   .map { it -> [it[0],
                 it.flatten().findAll{ it.getExtension=="bgen"},
                 it.flatten().findAll{ it.getExtension=="stat"}
                ]
   }
```